# Is there an extension for autocompleting selector name when editing the template (Angular project in VSC)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there An extension works like - IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTM
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

### Requirements:

1. selector's name could be autocompleted when editing inside the self component template
2. when the module is imported to another new module, inside the new module's template the selector's name could also be autocompleted when editing

## e.g.

**component.ts**

```
@component({
   selector: "common-app",
})
```

**component.html**

```
<common-app> ..... </common-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

use angular cli command. ng g c component, then you will get your components with decorator.